# Is the a way to print all the arguments of av without using ac in the body of the function

Tags: c, arguments

```
#include<stdio.h>
/**
 * main - prints all arguments without using ac
 * @ac: number of arguments in av
 * @av: array of strings (arguments)
*/

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < ac; i++)
    {
        (void) ac;
        printf("%s\n", av[i]);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `for(i = 0; i < ac; i++)`? Is it a home work to do it without `ac`? What do you know about the `av` array?

Comment: How do you expect to know how many entries are in what's supposed to be an array pointed to by `av` ?

Comment: yhaa without ac

Comment: yhaa that's exactly what's bugging me, anyways thanks @mch

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/ You can read this, there is a section "Properties of command line arguments". The point 4 should be very helpful for your task.

Answer (score 1):

The standard says in chapter 5.1.2.2.1 paragraph 2 among other statements:

> `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.

So you can loop through the array of pointers until you find a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can print all arguments passed to the command line using both `ac` and `av`. But your question is how to print arguments only by using `av`. Well, `av` is a NULL terminated array of string. So, you can loop until `av[i] != NULL`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(__attribute__((unused))int ac, char **av)
{
    int i;
    
    for (i = 1; av[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", av[i]);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: This was already posted as answer, 6 months ago.